# Calculating Time Difference with Current time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between two Dates but am getting different results when i use the current Date of the system.

```
const d = 1000*3600*24;
var str = new Date('07/30/2021');
var D = new Date(Date(0));
calc = str.getTime() - D.getTime();
result  = Math.floor(calc / d);
```

In the above result is **29**

```
const d = 1000*3600*24;
var day1 = new Date("06/30/2021");
var day2 = new Date("07/30/2021"); 
calc = day2.getTime() - day1.getTime();
result  = Math.floor(calc / d);
```

In the above result is **30**

Why is it that when i use the **Date(0)** function it gives me a different result. I need to use the **Date(0)** function get the current system date/time in AfterEffects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using Date(0) you have hours and minutes which affect the result

for Example : Sat Feb 06 2021 23:24:39

by using new Date("02/06/2021") you get this result : Sat Feb 06 2021 00:00:00

Comment: How can I strip the time from Date(0)

Comment: i was able to get in the current way : new Date(new Date(Date(0)).toDateString()).getTime()